# mysql statement in bash shell script does not work / syntax error

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, mysql, csv

hope someone can help me!
I do not know what's wrong with this script (Bash / Ubuntu 12.04 / Mysql / XAMPP 1.8.3).
Try to read an input file with a list of csv-filenames (449-R11, 449-R12 ..) in order to do some sql-statements....

```
    #!/bin/bash

     OUTPath="/home/bono/RD/BV-OUT/tmp/distinct_"
     OUTPath1="/home/bono/RD/BV-OUT/tmp/load_"
     INPath="/home/bono/RD/BV-OUT/"

     while read line do
     RD="$line"
     bv_out_distinct=$OUTPath$RD
     bv_out_load_new_bvs=$OUTPath1$RD
     RDDATEI=$INPath$RD

     ###MYSQLs:
     /opt/lampp/bin/mysql --local-infile --user=root RD << EOF 
     LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE $RDDATEI 
       INTO TABLE bv_tmp_all FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';';
     SELECT * FROM bv_tmp_all GROUP BY BAN 
       INTO OUTFILE $bv_out_distinct FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ;
     LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE $bv_out_distinct 
       INTO TABLE bv_tmp_distinct FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';';
     UPDATE bv, bv_tmp_distinct 
       SET bv.RD=bv_tmp_distinct.RD,bv.LEV21=bv_tmp_distinct.LEV21 
       WHERE bv.BAN=bv_tmp_distinct.BAN;
     SELECT * FROM bv_tmp_distinct 
       WHERE BAN NOT IN (SELECT BAN FROM bv) 
       INTO OUTFILE $bv_out_load_new_bvs FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';';
     LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE $bv_out_load_new_bvs 
       INTO TABLE bv FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';';
     TRUNCATE TABLE bv_tmp_distinct;
     TRUNCATE TABLE bv_tmp_all;
     EOF
     ##### EOSQL
     done < /home/bono/RD/BV-OUT/allto468
```

I tried different versions :( , nothing worked.... I get this mysql-output:

```
bono@bono-S3210SH:~/RD/procs$ ./load_RD_out_tmp

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
  check the manual that corresponds to your MyS INTO TABLE bv_tmp_all FIEL' 
  at line 1 to use near '"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE /home/bono/RD/BV-OUT/449-R11
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
  check the manual that corresponds to your MyS INTO TABLE bv_tmp_all FIEL' 
  at line 1 to use near '"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE /home/bono/RD/BV-OUT/449-R12
```

Answer (score 1):

Your file names should be escaped with quotes - MySQL considers them strings, so your MySQL block should be:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$RDDATEI' 
  INTO TABLE bv_tmp_all FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';';
SELECT * FROM bv_tmp_all GROUP BY BAN 
  INTO OUTFILE '$bv_out_distinct' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';';
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$bv_out_distinct'
  INTO TABLE bv_tmp_distinct FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';';
UPDATE bv, bv_tmp_distinct 
  SET bv.RD=bv_tmp_distinct.RD,bv.LEV21=bv_tmp_distinct.LEV21 
  WHERE bv.BAN=bv_tmp_distinct.BAN;
SELECT * FROM bv_tmp_distinct 
  WHERE BAN NOT IN (SELECT BAN FROM bv) 
  INTO OUTFILE '$bv_out_load_new_bvs' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';';
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$bv_out_load_new_bvs' 
  INTO TABLE bv FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';';
TRUNCATE TABLE bv_tmp_distinct;
TRUNCATE TABLE bv_tmp_all;
```

Comment: Thanks Rudu. But pity it does not work with the quotes. I get the message ' not found (Errcode: 2 - File or Directory not found). But when I put the content of the var into the SQLs directly it works. The files exist.... :(

Comment: Now I tried this (but it does not work either):  #!/bin/bash

    while read line do  
    RD="$line"
    RDDATEI="/home/bono/RD/BV-OUT/"
    RDDATEI+=$RD

    echo -e $RDDATEI
    ###MYSQLs:

    mysql --local-infile -u root -D RD << EOF
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$RDDATEI' INTO TABLE bv_tmp_all     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
    EOF
    ##### EOSQL
    
    done < /home/bono/RD/BV-OUT/allto468

Comment: The quotes were one problem. But it seems the var concat is an other!!! RDDATEI=$INPath$RD ---It seems that something is added you cannot see? If I type the full path and filename like RDDATEI="/home/bono/RD/BV-OUT/449-R11" --> works!